# Cant seem to share useContext or useReducer between components in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, use-context, use-reducer

Im wanting to use useContext() and useReducer(), to strip out redux to save another package and learn a new way of state management . I've hit a blocker.

In the login page after the reducer updates the payload. Which can be seen in the screen shots below. I can see the Context.Provider and the reducer values have been updated but if I were to console.log('context') I still get the initial value.

I want to share the updated payload between components is localStorage the only way to do this natively? Or am I missing something conceptually.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Here is the Context.Provider for AuthProvider - The context is also updated but when I navigate to /dashboard or dashboard.tsx the context goes back to initialState.]

[image: useReducer state has been updated but how do I share this between login + dashboard]

Here is my App.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root'
import { AuthProvider } from '~context/authContext'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import { StoreProvider } from 'easy-peasy'
import theme from '~styles/theme'
import { GlobalStyles } from '~styles/index'
import { Routes } from '~root/routes'
import { store } from '~store/index'

const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <StoreProvider store={store}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes />
      </AuthProvider>
    </StoreProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>
)

export default hot(App)
```

Here is my AuthProvider:-

```
import React, { FC, createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import authReducer, { authInitialState } from '~reducers/authReducer'
import { TState, IAuthProvider } from './types'

export const AuthContext = createContext<[TState, React.Dispatch<any>]>(undefined)

export const AuthProvider: FC<IAuthProvider> = props => {
  const authData = useReducer(authReducer, authInitialState)
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={authData}>{props.children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}

export const AuthConsumer = AuthContext.Consumer
```

Here is my authReducer:-

```
import { IAuthInitialState, IState, IReducerAction } from './types'
import { actions } from './actions'

export const authInitialState: IAuthInitialState = {
  accessToken: null,
  isAuthed: false,
  error: false,
}

const authReducer = (state: IState, action: IReducerAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.SET_ACCESS_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
      }
    case actions.RESET_ACCESS_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...authInitialState,
      }
    case actions.ERROR:
      return {
        ...authInitialState,
        ...action.payload,
      }
    default:
      throw new Error('Unexpected action')
  }
}

export default authReducer
```

Here is my Login page:-

```
import React, { FC, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Container, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useStoreActions, useStoreState } from '~store/hooks'
import { RedirectState } from '~root/routes/privateRoute'
import { StyledRow } from './styles'
import { AuthContext } from '~context/authContext'
import { getAccessToken } from '~utilities/index'

const Login: FC = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const { state } = useLocation<RedirectState>()
  const { isAuthenticated } = useStoreState(({ user }) => user)
  const [{ setUserModel }, { setSideNavModel }] = useStoreActions(({ user, sideNav }) => [user, sideNav])
  const [context, dispatch] = useContext(AuthContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    setSideNavModel({ title: 'login', activeChild: 'login' })
    const token = getAccessToken()

    const authData = {
      isAuthed: true,
      accessToken: token,
      time: Date(),
    }

    if (token) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'update',
        payload: authData,
      })

      localStorage.setItem('authedData', JSON.stringify(authData))
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Container id="page-container">
      <StyledRow className="justify-content-md-center">
        <Col md="auto"></Col>
      </StyledRow>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Login
```